# Selenium WebDriver doesn't press key while drag & drop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to test a scenario where a simple drag and drop moves the element and a drag and drop with CTRL key pressed copies the element.

The correct order in which copy works manually tested is:

1. hold element
2. move to target element
3. press CTRL
4. release element at target

This is my code:

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(element)
                .moveToElement(target).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .release().build();

        dragAndDrop.perform();
```

The thing is, the result is a move instead of a copy. So I guess it's ignoring the key press.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: I think this is not require : .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL) just remove it and try..

Comment: `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        Actions dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(element)
                .moveToElement(target).release().build();

        dragAndDrop.perform();`

Comment: On a side note, it seems awkward to first drag - then press control - then release for copying, as opposed to pressing control all the while.

Comment: Te control key needs to be pressed all the way up until after the release of the dragged element. Otherwise, the drop will start a move pop up instead of a copy one.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I have the exact same problem and webdriver::action does not execute the key_down and drag_and_drop at the same time.

Comment: I managed, but I used robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using robot. Here is code example:

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.setAutoDelay(500);

        Action drag = builder.clickAndHold(element).moveToElement(target)
                .build();

        drag.perform();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        Action drop = builder.release().build();
        drop.perform();
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```